# Exception when trying to implement Spinner

Tags: angular, typescript, spinner

I'm following the instructions at https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-spinner to implement a spinner within my application but obviously I am doing something wrong.

Here is my typescript module. Everything is working properly, however I'm not seeing any spinner even though I am showing it in ngOnInit and hiding it in the callback for getFacilities. (I know these methods are executing because I am getting the data displayed to the page.)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgxSpinnerService } from "ngx-spinner";
import { Portfolio} from '../models/Portfolio';
import { Facility } from '../models/Facility';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-member-component',
    templateUrl: './member.component.html'
})
export class MemberComponent {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private spinner: NgxSpinnerService ) { }

    public SelectedPortfolio: Portfolio = new Portfolio;
    public Portfolios: Portfolio[] = [] ;

    public SelectedFacility: Facility = new Facility;
    public Facilities: Facility[] = [];

    public UILock: boolean;

    ngOnInit() {

        // call the method on initial load of page to bind dropdown   

        this.spinner.show();
        this.UILock = true;

        this.SelectedPortfolio.name = "Select Portfolio";
        this.SelectedPortfolio.id = 0;

        this.SelectedFacility.name = "<No Portfolio Selected>";
        this.SelectedFacility.id = 0;

        this.getPortfolios();
    }

    public selectPortfolio(portfolio: Portfolio) {

        this.SelectedPortfolio = portfolio;

        this.getFacilities();
    }

    public selectFacility(facility: Facility) {

        this.SelectedFacility = facility;
    }

    private getPortfolios() {

        this.UILock = true;

        this.http.get<Portfolio[]>('https://localhost:44319/api/portfolio').subscribe((portfolios: Portfolio[]): void =>
          {
            this.Portfolios = portfolios;
            this.selectPortfolio(portfolios[0]);
          }
        );
    }

    private getFacilities() {

        this.http.get<Portfolio[]>('https://localhost:44319/api/portfolio/' + this.SelectedPortfolio.id).subscribe((facilities: Facility[]): void =>
            {
              this.Facilities = facilities;
              this.selectFacility(facilities[0]);
              this.UILock = false;
              this.spinner.hide();
            }
        );
    }
}
```

As soon as I add the following to my html template, all hell breaks loose.

```
<ngx-spinner bdColor="rgba(51,51,51,0.8)"
             size="medium"
             color="#fff"
             type="ball-scale-multiple">
  <p style="font-size: 20px; color: white">Loading...</p>
</ngx-spinner>
```

The page does not load and I see the following exceptions:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgxSpinnerComponent -> ChangeDetectorRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgxSpinnerComponent -> ChangeDetectorRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ChangeDetectorRef!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgxSpinnerComponent -> ChangeDetectorRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgxSpinnerComponent -> ChangeDetectorRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ChangeDetectorRef!
    at NullInjector.get (core.js:1354)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1681)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1607)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1470)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1681)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1607)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1470)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:23104)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:24192)
    at resolveDep (core.js:24722)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:30873)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
```

Here is my app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgxSpinnerModule } from "ngx-spinner";

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu/nav-menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ApiAuthorizationModule } from 'src/api-authorization/api-authorization.module';
import { AuthorizeGuard } from 'src/api-authorization/authorize.guard';
import { AuthorizeInterceptor } from 'src/api-authorization/authorize.interceptor';
import { MemberComponent } from './member/member.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        MemberComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
        ApiAuthorizationModule,
        NgxSpinnerModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'member', component: MemberComponent, canActivate: [AuthorizeGuard] },
        ])
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthorizeInterceptor, multi: true }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Thank you for your advice!

Perhaps my package.json is relevant?

```
{
  "name": "cashflow",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run Cashflow:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "8.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "8.0.0-rc.1",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "oidc-client": "^1.9.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.6",
    "@angular/cli": "8.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "8.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.9",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "~11.10.5",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "typescript": "3.4.5"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, I had two **node_modules** folders within the project. One in the correct location, within **ClientApp** (which is where the Angular application ‘lives’) and the other at the root of the web application (wrong!). Evidently there was a conflict.

I now understand that when constructing such an application, I am really building two applications – one on the server (in C#) and one on the client (Angular / Typescript). Visual Studio provides a unified editor environment where we can work on both apps at the same time but it is still two separate applications. Originally, before I really knew what I was doing, I installed my Angular modules through the Visual Studio console window and I did not realize that it’s important to set the folder location manually (**cd ClientApp**) before installing any package, otherwise it will end up in the wrong location. Here's what I did to clean this up:

1. Got rid of rogue **package.json**, **package-lock.json**, **angular.json** from the project root.
2. Uninstalled all Angular packages listed under **Dependencies/NPM**
3. Deleted **node_modules** folder from the project root
4. Ran **npm update** in the **ClientApp** folder.

Now everything is working properly! I did not even have to change a line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the commonmodule from @angular/common

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

Comment: Where do I add that? I tried adding the import - import { Common } from '@angular/common'; - to both app.module as well as to my component but in both locations I get the red squiggle and Intellisense tells me Common is declared but its value is never read. Can  you provide a code sample? Thanks!

Comment: I see your suggestion. I've added that to both app.module.ts and to mymodule.component.ts (MemberComponent). In both locations Visual Studio dims out the line and tells me that it's not being used. Adding the include has no impact - I still get the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

You Can handle Like This . [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-spinner-demo-fxutde?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
 showSpinner() {
    this.spinner.show();
    setTimeout(() => {
        /** spinner ends after 5 seconds */
        this.spinner.hide();
    }, 5000);
  }
```

Comment: That is indeed what I expect to happen. Did you see my code? And the exception I am receiving? That's my question. How come the code - this.spinner.show(); - which works for you, doesn't work for me?

Comment: @YossiGeretz were is your MemberComponent module can you share it

Comment: It's the first code-block in my original posting. Thanks!